# exporting png file to HTML using R2HTML

Tags: html, r

Hi R experts out there,

I have a word cloud but I wanted to make it an html file, so other people can use this wordcloud in their website. So.. I tried R2HTML but I need some guidance to deal with png file.
Here's my code :

```
library(tm)
library(RTextTools) 
library(reshape)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(R2HTML)

c <- "HTML frame creates framed output, with commands in the left frame, linked to output in the right frame. By default, a CSS file named R2HTML.css controlling page look and feel is output to the same directory. Optionally, you can include a CSSFile= option to use your own formatting file"

corpus<- Corpus(VectorSource(c))
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, tolower)
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, myStopwords)
dictCorpus<- corpus
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
dtm<- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)

dtm

dtm.df <- as.data.frame(inspect(dtm))

library(reshape)
dtm2.df <- t(dtm.df)

topx <- as.matrix(dtm2.df)
forwc <- sort(rowSums(topx),decreasing=TRUE)
forwc2 <- data.frame(word = names(forwc),freq= forwc)
pal1 <- brewer.pal(8,"Dark2")


### WORD CLOUD  #######
#######################
png("wordcloud_html_test.png", width=1280,height=800)
wordcloud(forwc2$word,forwc2$freq, scale=c(8,.5),min.freq=3,max.words=Inf, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0, colors=pal1, vfont=c("serif","bold"))
dev.off()
```

I saw some other example like the below to generate the plot in html format.

```
summary(cars)
out = plot(cars)
HTML(out, file = "testpage3.html")
```

So.. I tried to a bunch of things including something like this..

```
out <- {png("wordcloud_html_test.png", width=1280,height=800)
wordcloud(forwc2$word,forwc2$freq, scale=c(8,.5),min.freq=3,max.words=Inf, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0, colors=pal1, vfont=c("serif","bold"))
dev.off()}
HTML(out, file = "wordcloud.html")
```

but nothing really worked. Can someone guide me what's missing here?

Also, I read that (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2003-3.pdf) "this is not a real HTML file,as it does not even contain standard headers .... Is there any package that I can try to mitigate this? ( I tried R studio KnitR but i have some problem with R studio so I gave up.)

Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a function that take a png file and insert it in a new html file.

```
#' create a html file where we insert a png  image.
#' @param destdir full path to your destination html directory 
#' @param pngPath full path to your origin png
#' @param htmlfile  html final file

pngToHTML <- function(destdir =getwd(),     
                      pngPath ='Rplot.png',
                      htmlfile='mypng.html'
                      ){
  imgdir <- "figure"

  html.code <- '<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    </head>
    <body>
       <img src="figure/test.png"></img>
    </body>
  </html>'
  ll <- readLines(textConnection(html.code))
  ll <- gsub("src=(.*)",paste0('src="',imgdir,'/',
                         basename(pngPath),'"'),ll)
  imgdir=file.path(destdir,imgdir)
  if (!file.exists(imgdir)) {
    dir.create(imgdir)
  }
  else {
    file.remove(list.files(imgdir, full.names = TRUE))
  }
  file.copy(from=pngPath,imgdir)
  htmlfile=file.path(destdir,htmlfile)
  cat(ll, file = htmlfile,sep='\n')
  browseURL(paste("file:///", htmlfile, sep = ""))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So if I want someone to be able to view this html file on his desktop, does it mean that I have to know his directory path to destination html directory and path to png file?

Comment: @user1486507 No you generate the html file where you like. Than you should send the result (file +figure folder) as a zipped file .

Comment: Great. Thanks!! This is second time that you helped me!=)